# Infinite dimensional stochastic process that integrates to Brownian motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

For some application, I'm wondering whether there exists some stochastic process $X:[0,\infty)\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that for every measurable partition of $[0,1]$ into $\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ -- i.e. $A_i\in\mathcal B[0,1]$, $i\in[n]$, are disjoint Borel sets whose union is the unit interval -- it holds that the processes $Y_i(\cdot)=\int_{A_i}X(\cdot,x)\ \mathrm dx$ constitute independent Brownian motions.

I know of cylindrical Brownian motions, but when we use this construction, we either have a correlation structure on $[0,1]$; or we treat every $x\in[0,1]$ as a separate coordinate, in which case the underlying space would not be separable anymore.

Of course, by Kolmogorov's extension theorem, we can define a process $X(t,x)$ such that $X(\cdot,x)$ is a Brownian motion independent of $X(\cdot,y)$, $y\neq x$, but with such a construction there is no way to assure that the integrals $Y_i(\cdot)$ are well-defined.

I'm looking for either a reference or some direct answer.

Comment: Do you require that the $Y_i$ are standard Brownian motions, as suggested in the title, or just when you integrate on $[0,1]$? I assume you mean the latter, as in the former case you would have $Y_{[0,1]} = Y_{[0,1/2)} + Y_{[1/2,1]}$ by additivity, and the sum of two independent standard Brownian motions is still a BM, but with variance 2 i.e. not standard.

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit. Indeed, the property that is important to me is that the processes $Y_i$ are independent. Since we can always scale $X$, I dropped the requirement of having a *standard* Brownian motion

Comment: Let $W$ be a standard $L^2$ white noise on the strip $[0,\infty) \times [0,1]$, and formally let $X(t,x) = \int_0^t W(t,x) dt$ (so $X$ is a random distribution rather than a random function). Then the process $Y_i(t)$ is the integral of the white noise over the box $[0,t] \times A_i$, and so is a Brownian motion with variance $\text{Leb}(A_i)$, and the $Y_i$ will be independent. Is this what you are looking for? This may be what you mean by 'cylindrical Browninan motion', so I imagine it might not be.

Comment: @Julius This appears to be what I was looking for, thanks!